# Node JS MSSQL Callbacks

Tags: node.js, sql-server, callback

No matter how many different posts, books, tutorials, etc I read I can't seem to grasp promises. I'm trying to execute a chunk of code in Node after the SQL requests have completed, however I can't seem to make it work... Any help at all would be greatly appreciated. I need `console.log('done');` to run after the `for` loop has completed running through the `req` array:

```
app.post('/QueryWrite', function (req, res) {
var anyErrors = false;
sql.connect(config).then(function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.send(err);
        anyErrors = true;
    }
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < req.body['query[]'].length; i++) {
        var sqlQuery = req.body["query[]"][i];
        let sqlRequest = new sql.Request();
        sqlRequest.query(sqlQuery, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                res.send(err);
                anyErrors = true;
            }
        })
        console.log(req.body.authenticatedAs + " wrote to DB: " + sqlQuery);
    }
}).then(console.log('done'));
```

Comment: Hey Nate, in the most case you probably want to have a stable connection first when you run your server, not inside a request. Everytime creating a new connection might not be the best idea maybe what you can do is check the docs for mysql https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql I'll provide some more info for this example below

Comment: Bdw can you also provide a query sample there? :)

Comment: You might find `await` easier to understand, read and write. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await

Comment: @HalilÇakar here is what I use to make the post request: `$.post('/QueryWrite', { query: multiQueryObj, authenticatedAs: authenticatedAs.userID }, function(data) {...}`

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft, I've tried looking through those docs, however it looks like the function needs to return a promise? I don't quite understand that part and I can't rewrite the SQL connection method in the MSSQL library

Comment: Aight so if you want/need the second `then` you need to return a promise inside first one for sure. I'll try to write an example for you down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is kinda simplified example for database connection.

```js
// database.js file
const mysql = require("mysql");
const utils = require("util");

const dbCon = mysql.createConnection({
  debug: false,
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  database: "laravel_test_tweety",
  password: "",
  multipleStatements: true,
});

dbCon.query = utils.promisify(dbCon.query);

module.exports = dbCon;
```

So this is how i kinda use my database connections. After this lets try with server.js

```js
//server.js
// ... here your code with creation of app and such,
// and we are importing dbCon from database.js
const dbCon = require("./database");

// server that listens for requests called `app`
app.post("/QueryWrite", function (req, res) {
  /**
   * in case if you are sending an object as queries
   * we need them as array
   * { query1: 'some query', query2: 'some query' }
   *  =>
   * ['some query', 'some query']
   *
   * So that's why we are using `Object.values`
   */
  let queries = Object.values(req.body["query[]"]);
  if (queries) {
    // So there are couple of options here
    // Let's say you are only selecting stuff from db
    let query = queries.join(";");
    // This is gonna give you something like
    // "SELECT 1; SELECT 2"
    // If you want this to work you need `multipleStatements: true` on 
    // mysqlConfig from database.js
    dbCon
      .query(query)
      .then((results) => {
        console.log(results);
        // if needed do some stuff here and send res back.
        res.json(results);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
        // do some other stuff
      });
  }
});
```

After everything from here, If you need to do insert or update, you also need to be able to send data, I can't really get around my head to that right now but maybe with in the array seperate those and query one by one?

I'm aware that this is not exactly what you want but atleast for select or delete queries this would work.